# Get JSON data out of Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I am a frontend developer so forgive my lack of ability to explain my issue.

I am trying to create some pages in an Umbraco project that display data using Vue.js. For this, I am trying to set up a custom API controller that will return the data I want, when called.

A simple example would be that I want to return all blog articles. Below is the code I have currently got:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Umbraco.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Controllers.WebAPI.Qwerty
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostsApiController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "qwerty";
        }
    }
}
```

I've read numerous articles and just can't seem to grasp what I need to do to query Umbraco for the data I want back?

I've tried adding

```
var content = Umbraco.TypedContent(1122);
```

And then returning that but I get errors stating:

```
(local variable) Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent content
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' to 'string'
```

I have then tried serialising the `var content` but I get stuck with:

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'FooterCtalink' with type 
'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Blog'. Path 
'ContentSet[0].FeaturedProducts[0].Features[0].ContentSet[0]'.
```

Any help would be fantastic!

EDIT:

I have no edited the controller to be like this:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;
using Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DTOs.PostDTO;

namespace Controllers.WebAPI.Qwerty
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostsApiController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public PostDTO Test()
        {
            // 1. Get content from umbraco
            var content = Umbraco.TypedContent(1122);

            // 2. Create instance of your own DTO
            var myDTO = new PostDTO();

            // 3. Pupulate your DTO
            myDTO.Url = content.Url;

            // 4. return it
            return myDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

And created a DTO like so:

```html
namespace DTOs.PostDTO
{
    public class PostDTO
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
}
```

However, when console logging my data after the ajax request, I only only getting `1122`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't return a .NET Object in JSON that has the circular dependency.

To solve your problem, you can simply follow the below steps:

1. Create your own DTO & add required properties in that.
2. Fetch content from Umbraco API in C# & populate your custom DTO object.
3. Return that DTO from JsonResult.

Your code will look like below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PostsApiController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public MyDTO Test()
    {
        // 1. Get content from umbraco
        var content = Umbraco.TypedContent(1122);

        // 2. Create instance of your own DTO
        var myDTO = new MyDTO();

        // 3. Pupulate your DTO
        myDTO.SomeProperty = content.SomeProperty;

        // 4. return it
        return myDTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've attempted to use what you've suggested but my data seems to only return `1122`. I've updated the question with latest code.

Comment: This is not possible. Put a break-point there & ensure that the code which you written is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

I think you need to return ActionResult instead of string.

Something like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var content = Umbraco.TypedContent(1122);
        return new JsonResult(content);
    }
```

This should return the umbraco object as Json.

Comment: I'm getting the error `JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguements`